# Cascading ConfigureAwait(false), is it necessary?

Tags: async-await, configureawait

I am developing an MVC5 ASP.NET Application where I have the following question.

If I have an action in a controller defined this way:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> MyAction()
{
    await MethodAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
}
```

Then, if MethodAsync calls another async method, this way:

```
public async Task<bool> MethodAsync()
{
    await OtherMethodAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
}
```

Does it make sense to call again ConfigureAwait(false) inside the awaited method? Or should I use the default (ConfigureAwait(true))?.

Thanks
Jaime

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each method should make its own decision on whether to use `ConfigureAwait(false)`. If *that method* needs its context (in this case, `HttpContext.Curent` / culture / identity), then it should not use `ConfigureAwait(false)`.

Bear in mind that this code:

```
await MethodAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
```

is roughly the same as this code:

```
var task = MethodAsync();
var configuredTask = task.ConfigureAwait(false);
await configuredTask;
```

In other words, `MethodAsync` is called *before* `ConfigureAwait`. So the method is called *with* the current context, and then the task it returned is awaited *without* capturing the context.